# Same file different md5 hashes

Tags: c#, .net, file, hash

I have a winforms application where I have option of upload a .csv file. I am computing the file hash for the uploaded .csv file. If the contents of the file has changed then I display a message box saying the data of the file has changed.

I know how to compute the file hashes, but kind of stuck with how to store the old file hash of the same file and then comparing it with the new file hash of the same file.

```
static bool FileHashesAreEqual(FileInfo fileName)
{
     byte[] firstHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(firstName.OpenRead());
     var oldFileHash = firstHash;

     for (int i = 0; i < oldFileHash.Length; i++)
     {
         // Unable to figure out how to compare newFileHash and the oldFileHash
         //if (oldFileHash[i] != newFileHash[i])
         return false;
     }

     return true;
 }
```

Any help on how to do this is really appreciated.

Comment: Hash is not about file name or directory, it is just about the contents. If you change contents - a hash of file changes.

Comment: You can maintain the Dictionary with Key as fileName and Value as Hash Key. If the old key value is not same that's mean that hash has changed. If changed then you can update the previous value with new value.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Can you tell us **why** you are hashing the files?

Comment: So what are the hashes in either cases? What is the problem comparing them?

Comment: @mjwills - I am comparing the file hashes to display a message box saying the data in the file has changed.

Comment: if you have the files to be compared locally available, you better off just compare the two files byte by byte. MD5 is useful to check a file's integrity when you cannot compare your copy with the original file directly.

Comment: @PepitoSh - I thought byte by byte comparison is a slow process and hence thought I could check the file hashes.

Comment: Creating an MD5 hash requires reading through a file anyway. Plus some bit crunching. If you find any difference between the two files, you may stop your processing right after the first byte.

Comment: @PepitoSh - makes sense. I ll give it a try as well. Happy to learn new stuff:) Thanks :)

Comment: Linq's [.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) can help with byte comparison

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Thanks everyone for your ideas and comments.

```
private bool FileHashesAreEqual(FileInfo fileName)
{
    byte[] firstHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(fileName.OpenRead());

    if (!this.fileHashDictionary.ContainsKey(fileName.Name))
    {
        this.fileHashDictionary.Add(fileName.Name, firstHash.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.fileHashDictionary.TryGetValue(fileName.Name, out var value))
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
               for (var index = 0; index < value.Length; index++)
               {
                   if (value[index] != firstHash[index])
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
                }
             }
         }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use `ContainsKey`. Just use `TryGetValue`. If `value` is `null` then it wasn't there.

Comment: Also use `using` around `MD5.Create()` to ensure it is disposed.

Comment: @mjwills will change it :) Thanks :)